# Add a new object into QQmlListProperty

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I have a QQmlListProperty that store a list of custom C++ object.

So far I was able to create data in C++ and have QML receives those data. But I cannot figure out how to create data on the QML side and have it automatically send to C++.

```
QQmlListProperty<CustomData> Dataset::customDatas()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<CustomData>(this, this,
        &Dataset::appendCustomDatas,
        &Dataset::customDataCount,
        &Dataset::customData,
        &Dataset::clearCustomDatas
    );
}
```

If I understand correctly, the four functions defined here will give QQmlListProperty to behave "like a JavaScript array". This means I can either append new data to the array or clear the array and it will call appendCustomDatas and customData respectively.

But so far, I have not been able to find any example how to do that exactly.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking about the javascript syntax to add a new CustomData?

Comment: @Amfasis YES! I could not find that information from the doc.

Comment: Did you try `append` ? I don't use QQmlListProperty, the use of it seems very limited to me, I often go with a QAbstractListModel